# Can we access a relation loaded in Script A from Script B in Apache pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

My question is if there's a way to access a relation 'data1' build in sript1.pig from script2.pig without having to load the data again?

script1.pig has:

```
data1 = LOAD '$some_location'USING PigStorage('\t') AS (...);
```

RUN script2.pig;
 EXEC;

script2.pig has:

```
filter1 = FILTER data1 BY <<some-condition>>;
```

Can I access data1 in script2.pig, without having to reload data1 in script2.pig?

Comment: I would really appreciate if someone can provide an alternative solution.

Comment: No..............

Comment: I think you can, please have a look at my solution and let me know if any issue or if you require any other information from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Something I tried in my project to solve it and it worked:

runner_script.pig has:

```
RUN script1.pig; 
EXEC;

RUN script2.pig; 
EXEC;
```

script1.pig has:

```
data1 = LOAD '$some_location'USING PigStorage('\t') AS (...);
filter1 = FILTER data1 BY <<some-condition-1>>;
```

script2.pig has:

```
filter1 = FILTER data1 BY <<some-condition-2>>;
```

That way I didn't have to load the data1 twice.